# How to get a string after keyword

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I would like to get the string after a specific keyword.

For example:

```
import re
def findWholeWord(w):
return re.compile(r'\b({0})\b'.format(w), flags=re.IGNORECASE).search

abc = "<StephenCurry Pro='ThreepointShooter'>MVP1times</StephenCurry>"
if findWholeWord("SeedNumber")(abc):
    dddd = re.search('(?<=ThreepointShooter)(.\w+)', abc)
    mvp = dddd.gorup()
    print (mvp)

    print ("found")
else:
    print ("not found")
```

I expect the result suppose to be   **'MVP1times'**.

Is there any better method to find a specific string after keyword ? the result maybe a string, Digit or even mix like the result above.

Thanks for help!

Comment: [Why don't you use XML parser?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/38218040)

Comment: Because I want to try it in another way..thx for ur suggestion also, i have tried the XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use look-arounds to get the string surrounded by `>` and `<` (assuming this stays consistent):

```
>>> s = "<StephenCurry Pro='ThreepointShooter'>MVP1times</StephenCurry>"

>>> re.search(r'(?<=\>)[^<]+(?=\<)', s).group(0)
'MVP1times'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the regular expressiion to: `(?<=ThreepointShooter['|"]>)(.\w+)`. [See it live on http://pythex.org/](http://pythex.org/?regex=(%3F%3C%3DThreepointShooter%5B%27%7C%22%5D%3E)(.%5Cw%2B)&test_string=%3CStephenCurry%20Pro%3D%27ThreepointShooter%27%3EMVP1times%3C%2FStephenCurry%3E&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

I'm not sure what exactly your going to do but you don't even need to use lookbehind expression here.

Comment: Thx ! i will try and see

Comment: dddd = re.search("""?<=ThreepointShooter['|"]>)(.\w+)""" , abc) 

how do i avoid the quotation mark? I get none attribute in dddd for this case

Comment: originally my coding is:
dddd = re.search('(?<=ThreepointShooter)(.\w+)', abc)
   and your coding (?<=ThreepointShooter['|"]>)(.\w+) inside got one apostrophe.. so how do i avoid it?